# Will Fuzzy logic work in SQL Server 2014 BI version? Is there any alternative way of checking the similarity between names?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

Will fuzzy logic work in SQL Server 2014 BI version?

Is there any alternative way of checking the similarity between names or strings while comparing names in different databases?

Comment: Doesn't look like it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#SSIS_AT so you'd need to implement your own code using string similarity algorithms.

Comment: See [Name Matching](http://superuser.com/a/481592/102438) segment of this answer for some roll your own ideas

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I seem to have "lost" my instance of SSDT, so I'm afraid I can't verify this, yet. I found in previous version of SSIS that we could run a DTSX with Fuzzy Logic using BIDS, but because we weren't using Enterprise we couldn't run it with SQL Agent. It may be worth you testing this out in your version of SSDT as a quick test.

Comment: It Works fine in SSDT but it doesn't work using SQL Agent. Any alternatives to make it work in Agent?

Comment: Nope. For it to work in SQL Agent you'll need the appropriate version. I don't know if a fuzzy logic DTSX will run using the DTSX Exec utility, if it does then you could try running it as a scheduled task, or even write yer own Windows service.

Comment: I've re-installed SSDT and tried a simple DTSX with a Fuzzy Transform, via DTExec - no joy - it returns a message indicating enterprise is required. So looks like you're snookered!